# Outputting highscorelist of users in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, templates

I have messed up my code and as a beginner seek advice. What I want: to ouput a list of users and their total time in a quiz. The users adds his name to
localstorage and a time stamp, and the code looks like so

```
name = document.getElementById("name").value;
localStorage.setItem("name", name);

    function addZero(i) { // displays time in correct format 00:00:00
            if (i < 10) {
                i = "0" + i;
            }
            return i;
        }

        var d = new Date();
        var h = addZero(d.getHours());
        var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
        var s = addZero(d.getSeconds());
        time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        localStorage.setItem("time", time);

        });
```

So far so good. Name and time saved. Then comes the tricky part to output an array with the 5 fasters users. I've dabbled with the output:

```
    function displayHighScore (display, result, output) {

    display = document.querySelector("#highScoreTmpl");

    var highscoreArray = [];

    var displayName = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem.name);
    var startTime   = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem.time);
    var totalTime   = startTime - localStorage.setItem("time");
    var paired      = displayName.concat(totalTime);

    // push user results to array
    highscoreArray.push(paired);

    // sort array 
    highscoreArray.totalTime.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

    //present user results
    result  = document.querySelector("#highScoreTmpl");
    output  = highscoreArray.paired.toString();
    result.textcontent = output;

}
```

}

I want this to be displayed on an HTML page within a template. Preferrably in list element. Should i use a for loop? foreach?

```
<h2>[ Highscore ]</h2>
<template id="highScoreTmpl">

</template>
```

Bare in mind I am not at all certain of what I am doing in part two of the code here and a beginner. Any help hugely appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could do with reading up a little more on [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). You're trying to access data incorrectly in the `displayHighScore` function.

It also looks like you're trying to calculate a time period, which would make storing `d` in localStorage would make more sense, because when you calculate `totalTime` currently you're trying to perform maths on a string. This calculation should realy be

```
var totalTime = Date() - localStorage.startTime;
```

which (assuming you stored the `d` as `startTime` will give you the time elapsed on the quiz. At this point you want to apply the formatting that you're currently applying in the first code block.

Finally, once you've pushed the pair to `highscoreArray` and sorted it, you probably want to store the array so that you can see previous high scores as well. Three things to note here:

1. Your sorting method will currently sort alphabetically as you're passing a string to sort. You can modify the `function(a,b)` code to produce the sorting method you actually want.
2. You'll also need to retrieve the high scores array form wherever you choose to store it before you push and sort it
3. If you store the array in localStorage it'll only show times that have been achieved on that computer.

**Sorting method**

At the point of sorting your array, it will be filled with strings like `Dave 01:20:14` and `Johnny 00:45:02`. If you sort these alphabetically, the names will become ordered (Dave then Johnny), but you want to sort by their times.

To do this, inside your sort function, you'll need to split the strings `a` and `b` so you can compare the times rather than the text:

```
...function(a,b) {
    a_time = a.substr(a.indexOf(' ')+1);
    b_time = b.substr(b.indexOf(' ')+1);
    return a_time-b_time;
}...
```

Comment: Thank you Stuart for your input! Much appreciated.

Comment: "You can modify the function(a,b) code to produce the sorting method you actually want." How would I go about doing that, Mr Kemp?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.